# Cannot invoke MYSQL procedure within PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When i cnooect to my database and create a new table i then have a procedure to populate the table with data. The table is created fine however the procedure is not called and thus table not populated. When i run a SQL query it works fine and i have no idea what im doing wrong.

I got my SQL code from: https://gist.github.com/bryhal/4129042

here is my PHP code:

```
     mysqli_select_db($con,"db_name");
    mysqli_query($con, "CREATE TABLE test123 (
    id                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    db_date                 DATE NOT NULL,
    year                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    month                   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    day                     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    quarter                 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    week                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    day_name                VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    month_name              VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    day_type                VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT 'In' CHECK (day_type in ('In', 'Off', 'Training', 'Holiday')),
    weekend_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (weekday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
    event                   VARCHAR(50), UNIQUE td_ymd_idx (year,month,day), UNIQUE td_dbdate_idx (db_date) )Engine=MyISAM;");

    mysqli_query($con, " TRUNCATE TABLE test123;");



    mysqli_query($con, " CALL fill_date_dimension('2018-01-01','2020-01-01')" ) or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error() );
    mysqli_query($con, " OPTIMIZE TABLE test123");

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Whats confusing is ive had it working before but i must be overlooking something.

Thanks

Comment: Have you changed table name in procedure?

Comment: Good shout, something I definitely overlooked. The call query does fail. Maybe this is it? Could I pass a table as a parameter? Something I will have to try when I'm back home.

Comment: No, seems like you can't pass table name as param. You have to edit your stored procedure

Comment: What about adding the procedure code to the SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

fill_date_dimension(date1,date2); is not defined anywhere.
go and define it before calling.

```
mysqli_query($con, "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fill_date_dimension;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(IN startdate DATE,IN stopdate DATE)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE currentdate DATE;
        SET currentdate = startdate;
        WHILE currentdate < stopdate DO
            INSERT INTO time_dimension VALUES (
                            YEAR(currentdate)*10000+MONTH(currentdate)*100 + DAY(currentdate),
                            currentdate,
                            YEAR(currentdate),
                            MONTH(currentdate),
                            DAY(currentdate),
                            QUARTER(currentdate),
                            WEEKOFYEAR(currentdate),
                            DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%W'),
                            DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%M'),
                            'f',
                            CASE DAYOFWEEK(currentdate) WHEN 1 THEN 't' WHEN 7 then 't' ELSE 'f' END,
                            NULL);
            SET currentdate = ADDDATE(currentdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        END WHILE;
    END
    //
    DELIMITER ;");
```

Comment: Fill_date_dimension is a stored procedure in my mysql database